# USB EEPROM Flash Programmer with Linux support

Tags: usb, linux, memory

I bought a CH341 or similar ROM programmer (GZUT OnePro) from Ebay ages ago, but it has absolutely no Linux support whatsoever, and its Windows drivers are not WHQL which requires you to disable driver signature enforcement (massive security risk). Anybody not willing to get their driver signed or made open source has something to hide, and I am only ever willing to risk running it on my experimental computer which I use for kernel development.

Here is a different one that also has an extensive list of supported chips, but no Linux support (and not even Windows 10): https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/High-Speed-TL866CS-Programmer-USB-EPROM-EEPROM-FLASH-BIOS-AVR-AL-PIC/171997875525

The silly thing is that this could all be done with an Arduino with USB-UART (such as Leonardo) and just appear as a generic serial device, with automatic universal driver support. However, I cannot find a solid software package to flash to it.

Does anybody own a ROM programmer that they would recommend, that has Linux support, and a similar range of supported ROM chips to the one above?

Thank you!

Ps: I did look first, but if this is a duplicate post, I apologise.